# Preventing DPKG from upgrading package being installed

Tags: upgrade, software-installation, virtualbox, dpkg

I'm fairly new to the Linux world, so forgive me if the question is basic, I couldn't find an answer elsewhere.

When I run dpkg to install the version 5.1.14 of Virtualbox via `sudo dpkg -i ./debfile` followed by `sudo apt install -f`, i get:

```
    The following additional packages will be installed:
      virtualbox-5.1
    Recommended packages:
      libsdl-ttf2.0-0
    The following packages will be upgraded:
      virtualbox-5.1
```

The installed package ends up being version 5.1.32, which I do not want.
I know how to prevent a package from being upgraded *after* it's installed, but not *while* it's being installed.

I'm also forced to use dpkg because both apt and gdebi don't work for some reason, possibly because the version I want to install was meant for Ubuntu 16.10, and it's possible Virtualbox at version 5.1.14 won't work for me at all on Ubuntu 17.10, but I wish to try it anyway.

So, is there a way to force the installation of my preferred version, without it getting upgraded automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are not any missing depends, `sudo apt-get install -f` is unnecessary.

The following command will prevent changes to the package:

```
sudo apt-mark hold virtualbox-5.1
```